# 'PlotBackBrush' cannot expose type 'IRectangleBrush' outside the project through class 'PlotSurface2D'

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface

I have an interface

```
Public Interface IPlotSurface2D
   WriteOnly Property PlotBackBrush() As IRectangleBrush
End Interface
```

This is the class implementing the interface

```
Public Class PlotSurface2D
    Implements IPlotSurface2D

    Public WriteOnly Property PlotBackBrush() As IRectangleBrush _
        Implements IPlotSurface2D.PlotBackBrush

        Set(value As IRectangleBrush)
            Me.plotBackBrush_ = DirectCast(value, IRectangleBrush)
            Me.plotBackColor_ = DirectCast(Nothing, Object)
            Me.plotBackImage_ = DirectCast(Nothing, Drawing.Bitmap)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I get the follwoing compile error:

> Error  86  'PlotBackBrush' cannot expose type 'IRectangleBrush' outside the project through class 'PlotSurface2D'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `IRectangleBrush` is not public. Make it public.

Note: Since the interface `IPlotSurface2D` is public, it wants to expose (and must expose) all the types it references publicly. As a general rule we can say, that the access level of any type exposed by another type must not be more restrictive than the access level of this other type.

Comment: thank you that worked..was my carelessness did not check the interface.

Answer (score 4):

For error "cannot expose type  outside the project through module ..."

I inserted 'public'  before 'Module' that defined the type: Structure ... End Structure

Comment: Unbelievable.  Yes, the public module needs to be explicitly declared public.